Consumir recurso usuarios en .Net con Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient
Estoy intentado consumir el recurso de usuarios de un directorio de Microsoft 365, pero toda la información que encuentro al respecto usa algo similar a esto:
var azureUsers = await GraphServiceClient
        .Users
        .Request()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
          
        })
        .GetAsync();

Sin embargo yo no puedo usar el .Request() parece que ya no existe y solo puedo usar el GetAsyn().
var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();

A pesar de que esto funciona, no se como realizar un filtraje.
Alguien me puede decir si estoy haciendo algo mal, o es que ya no se usa de esta forma?
Estoy usando la versión 5.52 de Microsoft.Graph.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

El equivalente en la versión 5, sería:
var users =  await graphClient.Users.GetAsync(r => {
   r.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id" };
});

Aquí una guía de migración
